Which Arduino pin is giving gnd to the bus rail on a PCB?
I'm using a protoshield v2 for my Arduino Uno R3 project and I'm a little confused on how the bus rails works.
So I understand that the 5V pin from the Arduino is giving 5V to the 5V bus rail on the protoshield but which ground pin from the Arduino is giving gnd to the gnd bus rail of the PCB?
I labeled the gnd pins on the Arduino picture, is it just one of the pins going to the bus rail of the PCB? Or are all the pins the same and connected to the bus rail?



All the GND pins are connected together, and to the ground plane (a big copper portion of the board which "swallows" the other parts and tracks). Unlink power rails, GND pins of all circuits (e.g. arduino shields, external breadboard circuits) should be connected together, even if they have different power supply (3V3, 5V, 9V ...).

Please open the Protoshield schematics, and you will see how it connects.
It uses all GND pins.
